# Limiting the number of relationships for a given entity

Tags: database, entity-relationship, cardinality

Is there a way to limit the cardinality of a relationship in the database? Some friends and myself were fiddling with adding reactions to messages in slack, and now I'm wondering how you would enforce that only x reactions can be applied for a given uesr on a given message.

I'm just wondering how this would be implemented, as the only thing I could see using would be stored procedure to prevent the round trips to the database. Is there a general way being used?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a foreign key relationship, where potentially a great many rows can point to a given key.

Ensure that each row has a discriminant column, e.g. a confidence score, a random number, or a timestamp. Then just run a report that DELETEs rows to prune out older less interesting ones and bring you within your specified budget of `x`. A more expensive way to implement this would be to prune a single ancient row during an INSERT trigger.

Suppose you don't much care about the eviction policy, and `x == 2`. Then create a unique index on `(reaction_id, parity)`, compute the reaction's parity bit (maybe low order of sha1() digest), and use that for each INSERT. After two such reactions appear in the table, it's a sure thing that all future INSERTs will collide, so your UPSERT (update/insert) will automatically evict an old reaction, as desired.